# Can't make and receive sip calls using IMSDroid

Tags: android, sip, imsdroid, sip-stack

I trying to use [IMSDroid](https://github.com/DoubangoTelecom/imsdroid) sip-stack in order to make and receive calls between my android phone and an IP-camera which supports sip.

After providing the required options and logging in successfully, I tried to make a call from the camera to the phone but it didn't receive anything and instead it received the following in it's log:

```
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): ***ERROR: function: "tsdp_message_parse()" 
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): file: "src/parsers/tsdp_parser_message.c" 
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): line: "470" 
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): MSG: Failed to parse SDP message.
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): ***ERROR: function: "tsip_dialog_invite_process_ro()" 
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): file: "src/dialogs/tsip_dialog_invite.c" 
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): line: "456" 
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): MSG: Failed to parse remote sdp message:
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323):  [v=0
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): o=0 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.30.105
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): s=Dahua VT 1.5
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): c=IN IP4 192.168.30.105
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): t=0 0
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): m=audio 15000 RTP/AVP 0
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): 
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): 
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): ]
```

Then, when trying to make a call from the phone to the camera, it remains infinitely in the dialing screen with (outgoing call) address, and through that it keeps printing the following messages in the log:

```
08-31 15:18:05.500: E/tinyWRAP(21323): ***ERROR: function: "tsip_header_Date_parse()" 
08-31 15:18:05.500: E/tinyWRAP(21323): file: "src/headers/tsip_header_Date.c" 
08-31 15:18:05.500: E/tinyWRAP(21323): line: "387" 
08-31 15:18:05.500: E/tinyWRAP(21323): MSG: Failed to parse 'Date' header.
```

I can't figure out what is the problem, and for reference, this is how I configure the options:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 blank lines at the end of the message :

```
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323):  [v=0
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): o=0 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.30.105
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): s=Dahua VT 1.5
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): c=IN IP4 192.168.30.105
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): t=0 0
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): m=audio 15000 RTP/AVP 0
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): **HERE**
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): **HERE**
08-31 15:14:54.090: E/tinyWRAP(21323): ]
```

It may be the cause of the error ...
Did you update the IMSDroid sip-stack version to the lastest ?